# Prevent malicious flash ads in an iframe from redirecting users in the top location

Tags: javascript, flash, iframe

My site is laid out like this:

**{main page**    *(iframe containing flash ad)* **}**

Sometimes malicious flash ads load in the frame and redirect the user to a site of their choosing. I imagine they use the getURL() function in actionscript.

As I own the top page as well as the page inside the frame and am therefore able to edit the html for both is there anyway of preventing the flash ad from sending requests through the iframe to change the top location.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Something like `allowscriptaccess="never"` for embed/object tags.

Comment: If I add that to the iframe or embed tag I think it will prevent the flash ad from running at all as most ad companies use javascript to invoke the flash ad.

Comment: So to summarise there's not really any way to do this without preventing all ads from working?

Comment: In summary, ads taking over your website should not be included.

Answer (score 2):

*HTML5 to the rescue!*

Just add this to your iframe:

```
sandbox="allow-scripts"
```

This iframe sandbox feature prevents anything in the iframe from redirecting the page or performing any top frame navigation.

The one value you want is:

```
allow-scripts - Allows script execution
```

The other three sandbox options you don't want are:

```
allow-same-origin - Allows the iframe content to be treated as being from the same origin as the containing document
allow-forms - Allows form submission
allow-top-navigation - Allows the iframe content to navigate (load) content from the containing document
```

Fully 'sandboxed' iframe:

```
sandbox=""
```

Fully capable iframe:

```
sandbox="allow-scripts allow-forms allow-same-origin allow-top-navigation"
```

(or simply omit the property)

Comment: This works, however it's important to note that it's only supported by Chrome and Safari (for now). http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_iframe_sandbox.asp